# Error:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm very new to programming and I keep on getting this error eventhough I checked for nulls...I can't figure out why it is still giving me this error. 
This is my code in my ProjectDetailsViewModel:

```
 public List<string> SelectedServices
        {
            get
            {
                var services =
                    Project.Services?.Select(x => x.ProjServiceCode).ToList();
                var service = Project.ProjectPricings.Where(x=>x.ProjectId == Project.Id && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ServiceCode))
                    .Select(x => x.ServiceCode)
                    .ToList();
                var serviceList = new List<string>();
                if (services != null) serviceList.AddRange(services);
                serviceList.AddRange(service);
                return serviceList ;
            }
        }
```

and here I'm using it in the View:

```
 <tr class="control-oddrow">
        <td class="control-label">
            <label class="dcl-control-label required">Addt'l Services:</label>
        </td>
        <td class="spacer-column"></td>
        <td class="control-input">
            @{ var services = Model.SelectedServices ?? new List<string>() ; }

            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => services, new MultiSelectList(Model.ProjectServices, "ServiceCode", "ServiceCode", services))
        </td>
    </tr>
```

everytime I want to get the details of a project that the services in null, it throws this error. i would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this:
   if(Project.ProjectPricings!=null)

This is the whole function after I made it work:

```
   public List<string> SelectedServices
        {
            get
            {
                var service=new List<string>();
                var services =
                    Project.Services?.Select(x => x.ProjServiceCode).ToList();
                if(Project.ProjectPricings!=null)
                    service = Project.ProjectPricings.Where(x=>x.ProjectId == Project.Id && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ServiceCode))
                        .Select(x => x.ServiceCode)
                        .ToList();
                var serviceList = new List<string>();
                if (services != null) serviceList.AddRange(services);
                serviceList.AddRange(service);
                return serviceList ;
            }
        }
```